# How to know which file is calling which file, filesystem

Tags: python, logging, filesystems

How to know which file is calling which file in filesystem, like file1.exe is calling file2.exe 
so file2.exe is modified, 
and file1.exe is entered in log file.

winos

I have searched INTERNET but not able to find any samples.

Answer (score 0):

In order know which file is calling which file you can use the ***Trace module***

exp: if you have 2 files

```
***file1.py***
import file2
def call1():
    file2.call2()

***file2.py***
def call2():
    print "---------"
```

u can use it using console:

```
 $ python -m trace --trackcalls path/to/file1.py
```

or within a program using a Trace object

```
****tracefile.py***
import trace,sys
from file1 import call1

#specify what to trace here
tracer = trace.Trace(ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix], trace=0, count=1)
tracer.runfunc(call1) #call the function call1 in fille1  
results = tracer.results()
results.write_results(summary=True, coverdir='.')
```

Comment: [http://pymotw.com/2/trace/#tracing-execution], [https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html ]  for more options of this module